# WFFM Multiple Send Email Save Actions

Tags: wffm

I tried to add 2 send email save actions to a form and only the first one fired.

I debugged and the send email code was only hit once. These are both using the standard Send Email Message save action that should work OOTB, right?

I'm using Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 151207) and Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 151008.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work OOTB. I'm assuming you are testing it against the web db. Have you published the Save action after adding the two Save Actions? You can switch to the web db from the desktop and confirm you see the two save actions.